# PHP Destroy session on isset

Tags: php, session

I am trying to destroy a session when a session is selected but it is not being destroyed:

```
if (isset($_POST['primary_cat'])) {
    $_SESSION['primary_cat'] = $_POST['primary_cat'];
    unset($_SESSION['secondary_cat']);
}elseif(empty($_SESSION['primary_cat'])) {//define primary_cat
    $_SESSION['primary_cat'] = null;
}
```

When I change `$_POST['primary_cat']` this is changed but `$_SESSION['secondary_cat']` is not being destroyed. How can I destroy `$_SESSION['secondary_cat']`

Comment: This should work. Sure you're not assigning something back to `secondary_cat` later on in your code?

Comment: you are probably using it somewhere else after unsetting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I completely destroy the one and only session I have:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"],$params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
        echo " Zerstöre Cookie... ";
    }
    @session_unset();
    @session_destroy();
```

Maybe it helps you to adapt your code for your specific session.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the OP wants to destroy the *entire* session; just a single key.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['primary_cat'])) {
    $_SESSION['primary_cat'] = $_POST['primary_cat'];
    unset($_SESSION['secondary_cat']);
} elseif (empty($_SESSION['primary_cat'])) {//define primary_cat
    $_SESSION['primary_cat'] = null;
}
```

You should try these instead:

```
if (isset($_POST['primary_cat'])) {
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['primary_cat'] = $_POST['primary_cat'];
} else if (!$_SESSION['primary_cat']) {
    //your business
}
```

An explanation to that is on clicking or selecting

```
"primary_cat"
```

it should run that block of code else it won't run that code and if it does, you the

```
session_destroy();
```

Destroys active session and the below creates a new session due your specifications.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems ok, problem might be from your browser.

make sure session is started. if it's still not destroyed, then close your browser and restart apache.

But also make sure you are not setting `$_SESSION['secondary_cat']` somewhere else your code.

To be sure, do the following after unsetting `$_SESSION['secondary_cat']`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['secondary_cat'])){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("the session still has value : '.$_SESSION['secondary_cat'].'");</script>';
}
else
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("session has been unset");</script>';
```

The above will display a javascript alert showing "the session still has value : thevalue" if the session was not `unset` or "session has been unset" if it really has been `unset`

hope this helps

Comment: This sounds dangerously like cargo cult programming. Setting a value to `null` before you `unset` it should make zero difference.

Comment: Don't mind me, That's what i do when everything seems ok and they still don't work, very frustrating...so i usually temporarily resort to crazy stuff or "cargo cult"

Answer (score -2):

try this...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['secondary_cat'])&&!empty($_SESSION['secondary_cat'])){
        unset($_SESSION['secondary_cat']);
    }
```

Comment: 1) `isset && !empty` is redundant, just use `!empty`, 2) `if (isset) unset` is super redundant, just call `unset`. Nothing will happen if the key doesn't exist.